# How can I search in vim for a line that has 2 specific words?

Tags: vim

I want to find a line that has both 'foo' and 'bar' in this order but not necessarily next to each other.

I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
/foo.*bar
```

Comment: Maybe your problem is the 'magic' setting. Read :help 'magic' and :set magic? to see if that's the problem.

Comment: that was it... what is magic?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use:

```
:set magic
/foo.*bar
```

The 'magic' setting determines how VIM treats special characters in regular expressions. When it's off VIM treats all chars literally, meaning that the expression you wrote `foo.*bar` will actually search for that string. However, when 'magic' is on then special regex chars get their special meaning and it works more like you expect. It is recommended to always use `:set magic` unless dealing with really old Vi scripts, so just add it to your vimrc and you'll be set.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a default nowadays (at least my vim's on windows).

Comment: I agree, it is also the default for, but I don't know why it wasn't set for Sasha - perhaps he's using an older version or invoking vi instead of vim.

Answer (score 12):

Works for me:

```
/text.*text2
```

Comment: Ditto; case-insensitive: /FOO.*BAR\c

Comment: Unfortunately "works for me" doesn't give reason(s) why or likely cause(s).

Answer (score 4):

`h: search-pattern`

**1.** A pattern is one or more branches, separated by "\|".  It matches anything that matches one of the branches.

Example: `foo\|beep` matches "foo" and matches "beep".  If more than one branch matches, the first one is used.

**2.** A branch is one or more concats, separated by `\&`.  It matches the last concat, but only if all the preceding concats also match at the same position.

Examples:
        `foobeep\&...` matches "foo" in "foobeep".
        `.*Peter\&.*Bob` matches in a line containing both "Peter" and "Bob"

Comment: 2. is really helpful, i often encounter such situations. +1 for that

Comment: Seems `.*` prefix is necessary for each pattern, when search lines contain `both` pattern.

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question? You search pattern finds either the first or the second, not the first AND the second, as specified in the original question.